# How to get unmatched and missing records from two table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables Table1 and Table2 with some records

How to select column unmatched and missing records from two table in sql server

Table1

```
id      name     place

1        AAAA     bangalore

2        BBBB      IDLE

3        CCCC     Chennai

4        DDDD    NOT Reachable
```

Table 2

```
id     name     dept             place           

1       AAAA     IT                   bangalore

2       BBBB     Sales              mumbai

3       CCCC    Support         Chennai

4       DDDD    IT                   Delhi

5       MMMM    Software                   Mumbai
```

I want the result like this

```
id      name    

2        BBBB    

4        DDDD    

5   MMMM
```

i have got unmatched rows using below. how can I get unmatched and missing one in single select query?

```
select   t2.name[place from table2]
from tab1 t1 inner join tab2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.place <> t2.place
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . If I understand correctly, you want everything from `table2` that doesn't have a corresponding match in `table1`.  For that, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name and
                        t1.place = t2.place
                 );
```